# Where can you use the team defined in a User record Team related list?

Tags: user, teams

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I can't find any documentation on this anywhere online. I am trying to find out how the team that shows on a user record can be used within Salesforce? From what I can tell it is not used in reporting, so where and why is it used, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What teams are you referring to? Account or Opportunity Teams perhaps?

Comment: @crmprogdev I don't think it is Account or Opportunity team. It shows as a related list on the user record and is controlled by the manager field on the user. It defines the team as the user's manager, anyone with the same manager as the user, and anyone who has the user as their manager.

Comment: That's a customization that your org has created specific to your hierarchy. This would be helpful in defining approval processes.

Comment: @crmprogdev That's standard functionality I believe, not a customization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the team is used anywhere. I searched for APIs if I find any information about the team listed on the user profile. As per [this](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000230928&language=en_US) knowledge article, we can add users to the list by adding them as a manager. So, the list I think is only for representational purpose. The list contains,

```
1) Users we share the manager with(Colleagues)  
2) Users we are managing to
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**What is the Team listing on a user detail? Answer:**

Approval requests can automatically be routed the person you select as "approver manager" in your user detail.

The Team listing on your user detail shows the list of users who:
1.) have selected you as their approver manager,
2.) have the same approver manager as you, or
3.) are *your* approver manager.

This Team list is just for reference, it doesn't really do anything. So do NOT confuse it with the Teams Related List / Team Roles on Opportunity, Account, or Case (which are for record sharing). Also do NOT confuse with Role Hierarchy where users under a "manager" (someone above them in the roll hierarchy) are considered their "Team" for the purpose of viewing dashboards or record sharing.

Approval User Preferences
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.approvals_change_approval_user_pref.htm&type=5

Add a User to a Team on the User detail page
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000337311&type=1

[image]